# Good django middleware/example source for adding "reviews" to models?

Tags: python, django

I've become extremely frustrated trying to use django-reviews. I've looked through the [documentation](http://packages.python.org/django-reviews/), which is very sparse, and the source code, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use it. To boot, none of the templates are included.

Are there any other alternatives or perhaps some opensource projects that contain simple/flexible review capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need examples - django has great coverage of [generic relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) in docs. Also, bundled comments framework is "review app" of some sort. You can attach a comment to any object in the system, add field for a rating and you have review system :)

Answer (score 1):

Paperino, if you want to review a particular model, couldn't you add two more models, call it review_product (if what you want to review are models) and reviews.
Then review_product has three foreign keys, one to the product model, another to the review table and another to the user who has made the review.  The review table will have the specific review (description, stars, tags..).

That's how I implemented the review system in my application.